# The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support PowerShell version 2.0. Upgrade to PowerShell version 3.0 or higher

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want use `EF Core` in `Asp.net core` so i follow this [Instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db)
but when i want to use this command:`Add-Migration first` for creating database in PackageManger console, it gives me this error:

> The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support PowerShell version 2.0. Upgrade to PowerShell version 3.0 or higher, restart Visual Studio, and try again.

what is the problem?

NOTE: this is my `Project.json` file:

```
{
 "dependencies": {
   "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
     "version": "1.0.1",
     "type": "platform"
   },
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },

 "frameworks": {
   "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "portable-net45+win8"
     ]
   }
 },

 "buildOptions": {
   "emitEntryPoint": true,
   "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

 "runtimeOptions": {
   "configProperties": {
     "System.GC.Server": true
   }
 },

 "publishOptions": {
   "include": [
     "wwwroot",
     "**/*.cshtml",
     "appsettings.json",
     "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Install the latest version of PowerShell as instructed in the error message

Comment: @ErikEJ how can i do it? i search about it too, but didn't find any good result

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-windows-powershell

Comment: @Dmitry i have windows7 and visual studio 2015 update3 on it, it may my windows version cause this problem?

Comment: Manual contains section for Windows 7 too - did you executed steps described there?

Comment: Alternatively, if you installed [.NET Core with SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core), you can use [dotnet CLI commands to work with migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

Comment: @Dmitry when i do that steps i give u the result, thanks

Answer (score 1):

First Download latest version of NuGet from below link

https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe

Then download below exe and install it.

https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/7/6/E76850B8-DA6E-4FF5-8CCE-A24FC513FD16/Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu

After Installation restart your machine and open your visual studio.

it will work for me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can Download Windows Management Framework 3.0 
[link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)